# Read specific fields from Postgres jsonb

Tags: postgresql, json

I have data like

```
{"name": "a", "scope": "1", "items": [{"code": "x", "description": "xd"}, {"code": "x2", "description": "xd2"}]}
{"name": "b", "scope": "2", "items": [{"code": "x", "description": "xd"}]}
{"name": "c", "scope": "3", "items": [{"code": "x", "description": "xd"}]}
{"name": "d", "scope": "4", "items": [{"code": "x", "description": "xd"}]}
```

I want to filter out some fields in the json objects in my SELECT result, and the result could be something like:

```
{"name": "a","items": [{"code": "x"}, {"code": "x2"}]}
{"name": "b","items": [{"code": "x"}]}
{"name": "c","items": [{"code": "x"}]}
{"name": "d","items": [{"code": "x"}]}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Will the text to be removed always be `"scope"` followed by a number in double quotes and always `"description"` followed by a string in double quotes? Or are the patterns more difficult than that?

Comment: Also, you have `"a","items":` do you require a space between the `"a",` and `"items":`?

Comment: Welcome. In order to help us help you can you follow the steps here https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `your_jsonb_column - 'scope'` would be the first step. But for the nested array elements, you will need to iterate over them, remove the items you don't want and the put them together using `jsonb_agg()`

Comment: I want to filter out some fields from the json object, spaces don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not pretty (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bc462c1733d27cf64bb721eedfae3c57)):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  j_str TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES 
('{"name": "a", "scope": "1", "items": [{"code": "x", "description": "xd"}, {"code": "x2", "description": "xd2"}]}'),
('{"name": "b", "scope": "2", "items": [{"code": "x", "description": "xd"}]}'), 
('{"name": "c", "scope": "3", "items": [{"code": "x", "description": "xd"}]}'),
('{"name": "d", "scope": "4", "items": [{"code": "x", "description": "xd"}]}'),
('{"name": "a", "scope": "1", "items": [{"code": "x", "description": "xd"}, {"code": "x2", "description": "xd2"}, {"code": "x3", "description": "xd3"}]}');
```

Notice that I've added a record with 3 codes!

And the first step (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bc462c1733d27cf64bb721eedfae3c57)):

```
SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE
(
  j_str, 
  '(^.*,)( "scope": "\d{1,3}", )("\w{5}": \[\{"\w{2,10}": "\w{1,5}")(, "\w{10,15}": "\w{1,10}")',  -- ("\w10,15": "\w{2,10}")', 
  '\1 \3'
) FROM test;
```

which gives:

```
regexp_replace
{"name": "a", "items": [{"code": "x"}, {"code": "x2", "description": "xd2"}]}
{"name": "b", "items": [{"code": "x"}]}
{"name": "c", "items": [{"code": "x"}]}
{"name": "d", "items": [{"code": "x"}]}
{"name": "a", "items": [{"code": "x"}, {"code": "x2", "description": "xd2"}, {"code": "x3", "description": "xd3"}]}
```

Explanation of the regexp:

```
'(^.*,)( "scope": "\d{1,3}", )("\w{5}": \[\{"\w{2,10}": "\w{1,5}")(, "\w{10,15}": "\w{1,10}")',
'\1 \3'
```

Start from the beginning of the string (`^`) anchor, then go to the first occurrence of the word " scope" (note preceding space) which is then followed by a double-quote and then by 1 to 3 digits (`\d{1,3}`) followed by a double-quote then a comma and another space then followed by `"\w{5}"....` - the rest of the string! The round brackets `(...)` are `"capturing groups"` - so in the replacement string I have \1 (means the first capturing group) followed by the third - so the second one is deleted.

and then:

```
SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE
(
  REGEXP_REPLACE
  (
    j_str, 
    '(^.*,)( "scope": "\d{1,3}", )("\w{5}": \[\{"\w{2,10}": "\w{1,5}")(, "\w{10,15}": "\w{1,10}")', 
    '\1 \3'
  ), 
  '\{("code": "\w{1,10}")(, "\w{10,20}": "\w{1,9}")(\})', 
  '{\1\3', 'g' 
)
FROM test;
```

Result:

```
regexp_replace
{"name": "a", "items": [{"code": "x"}, {"code": "x2"}]}
{"name": "b", "items": [{"code": "x"}]}
{"name": "c", "items": [{"code": "x"}]}
{"name": "d", "items": [{"code": "x"}]}
{"name": "a", "items": [{"code": "x"}, {"code": "x2"}, {"code": "x3"}]}
```

So, you can see that the data is in your desired format! With a bit of work, it should be possible to use one single regexp for all of this - I can see a way of doing it which shouldn't require a specific `"scope"` or `"code"` words to be present - i.e. formulate the capturing groups in such a way as to combine regex 1 with the second one. Might be a good exercise?