# MySQL - Search Alphanumeric string using wildcards - underscore (_) and asterisk (*)

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching, string-searching

I have a table, `products`, with a `product_id` column as follows:

```
product_id
110177
110177T
177
```

I am trying to filter down the product results that should fetch result as below but it is also fetching the id `177`

```
110177
110177T
```

Query - `select * from products where produuct_id like %'177'%`

What updates in query to discard the string `177` in search result and only fetch rest of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eliminate the `177` value, you have to do the following (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ec7796ca5c322cb110e578d53636435)):

```
CREATE TABLE p (p_id VARCHAR (25));
```

and populate it:

```
INSERT INTO p VALUES
('110177'),
('110177T'),
('177');
```

and then run the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM p WHERE p_id LIKE '___177%';
```

Result:

```
p_id
110177
110177T
```

Note that the `___177%` (3 underscores) predicate here will pick up all values that have 3 characters (**any** single character) followed by 177 followed by any other characters or none.

This is due to the difference between the `%` (percent) wildcard and `_` (underscore) - the `_` means that the placeholder represents **one, and precisely one** character whereas the `%` wildcard represents **0 or more** characters.

So, the `177` isn't picked up because it has **no** characters before the 177 - it's  explained well [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-wildcards.htm).

The `!=` solution proposed by @Akina will also work but it implies knowing the values to be excluded in advance - my reading of your question is that you want to eliminate any really short `product_id`s and not just particular ones!

If you have more sophisticated requirements, you should take a look at regular expressions - an example from PostgreSQL can be found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/284521/34007) - MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html).

p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: This understanding is correct - *my reading of your question is that you want to eliminate any really short product_ids and not just particular ones*. It could be anything unknown but should be eliminated if not matched

Comment: This would work? - SELECT * FROM p WHERE p_id LIKE '___id%'; where id is passed dynamically

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy How do you mean, exactly, "passed dynamically"? What is your coding environment?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy - What client are you using?  Or you can build the like string with `CONCAT`.  (We need more details on what you have and what you really want.)